# How to add all addresses in Outlook.com inbox to safe senders list?

Tags: outlook.com

My problem right now is that there are lot of email addresses which I've already added to the safe senders list in Gmail, but not yet in Outlook.com. It would be really tedious to add them all one by one.

So how can I add all the addresses in my email inbox to the safe senders list so that they'll all load images, etc. by default?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see a way to add them all in one, but you can add a whole domain (the part of an email address after the @ sign).
If you import all your contacts they will automatically be a part of the safe senders list.